# Analiticity of function $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, holomorphic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Please help me this problem:

Which is the largest region where $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2z}$ is an analitic function?, where is f a meromorphic function?

Thansk for your support.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+n^2 z}$ has a simple pole at $z=-\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $f(z)$, together with its formal derivatives, is a uniformly convergent series... where?

Comment: I dont understand last part on your comment, may you clear it, please. so thanks

Comment: What techniques do you know for proving that a series of meromorphic functions is analytic/meromorphic over some domain? You may notice that $0$ is a limit point of simple poles. What happens if you remove from $\mathbb{C}$ a open neighbourhood of the origin? Are you able to prove $f$ is meromorphic over such domain?